# JavaScript AppendChild on an Array creating element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to update a page when a form is submitted with a success message and it will replace a form that is currently there. So right now I have:

```
function pageUpdate(){
 document.querySelectorAll('.form-inside').forEach(e => e.remove());
 var tag = document.createElement("p");
 var text = document.createTextNode("Thanks");
 tag.appendChild(text);
 var form_contain = document.getElementsByClassName('form-container');
 form_contain.appendChild(text);
}
```

This failsat this point with two different sections. I thought I could do something similar with the remove and do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.form-container').forEach(e => e.appendChild(tag));
```

This works...but not really. It's actually only applying to the last one not both. Is there a clear way to appendChild to multiple with the same class?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like structure.  An array like structure will not have the `appendChild` method on it

Comment: Your second snippet is appearing to only put the element on the last parent, because an element can only have a single parent.  When you append it to another element, it removes it from the previous one.  To append to all of them, you will need to clone the element for each parent.

Comment: Side note: this could be as simple as changing it to `.forEach(e => e.innerHTML += tag.outerHTML);`

Comment: @Taplar — `appendChild` takes a node as its argument, not a string.

Comment: @Quentin yeah, I thought of that and was adding to the comment as you replied

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('.form-container').forEach(e => e.innerHTML += tag.outerHTML); works!

Comment: Keep in mind, that approach would not be the correct way to solve this issue if you had added event listeners to any part of the `tag` or its children.

Answer (score 0):

An element can't appear in multiple parts of the document at the same time.

If you append it to element A, then append it to element B, it has to be removed from A so it can be placed in B.

You need to create the element and populate it each time you loop.